# Load script file dynamically in Blazor server

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have this javascript in _Host.cshtml before closing body tag:

```
<script>
    var loaded = false;
</script>
<script >
    window.importScript = (scriptUrl) => {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = scriptUrl; //"scripts/tinymce.min.js";
        script.onload = "loaded=true;"
        var timer = setTimeout(function () {
            if (loaded === true) {
                clearInterval(timer);
                document.body.appendChild(script);
            }                
        }, 100);            
       
    }
</script>
```

and this is my blazor index page:

```
@if (tinyMCELoaded)
{
    <TextArea MenuMode="MenuModeEnum.bloated" Value="hello">

    </TextArea>
}

@code {    
    bool tinyMCELoaded = false;
    protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);

        if (firstRender)
        {
            await jsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync(identifier: "importScript", "scripts/tinymce.min.js");            
            tinyMCELoaded = true;
            StateHasChanged();            
        }
    }
}
```

the code works partially, sometimes html editor loads and sometimes blazor error comes and says "tinyMce is not defined" (meaning the script file is not loaded), and after refreshing the page Editor appears.

How to have the editor always load with the first page load and without refreshing again.